# Passing parameters to bash when executing a script fetched by curl

Tags: bash, curl, parameter-passing

I know how to execute remote Bash scripts like this:

```
curl http://example.com/script.sh | bash
```

or

```
bash < <( curl http://example.com/script.sh )
```

which give the same result.

But what if I need to pass *arguments* to the bash script? It's possible when the script is saved locally:

```
./script.sh argument1 argument2
```

I tried several possibilities like this one, without success:

```
bash < <( curl http://example.com/script.sh ) argument1 argument2
```

Answer (score 102, accepted):

try

```
curl http://foo.com/script.sh | bash -s arg1 arg2
```

bash manual says:

> If  the  -s  option  is  present, or if no arguments remain after option processing, then commands are read from the standard input.  This option allows the positional parameters to be set when invoking an interactive shell.

Comment: Thanks ! Extremely useful with gists :)

Comment: What about parameters that use keys like `-p blah -d blah`?

Comment: The `read` in script is directly ignored by this way, how to fix this?

Comment: @hwding My answer below features that 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/72207423/4374258

Answer (score 148):

To improve on [jinowolski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642915/passing-parameters-to-bash-when-executing-a-script-fetched-by-curl/4642975#4642975) a bit, you should use:

```
curl http://example.com/script.sh | bash -s -- arg1 arg2
```

Notice the two dashes (--) which are telling bash to not process anything following it as arguments to bash.

This way it will work with any kind of arguments, e.g.:

```
curl -L http://bootstrap.saltstack.org | bash -s -- -M -N stable
```

This will of course work with any kind of input via stdin, not just curl, so you can confirm that it works with simple BASH script input via echo:

```
echo 'i=1; for a in $@; do echo "$i = $a"; i=$((i+1)); done' | \
bash -s -- -a1 -a2 -a3 --long some_text
```

Will give you the output

```
1 = -a1
2 = -a2
3 = -a3
4 = --long
5 = some_text
```

Comment: An excellent suggestion, and very clear as to the reason why you should do this.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. This trick is really useful!

Comment: for extra safety, it's advisable to use `curl --fail ...`. It makes curl stop on a 404, for example. A common set of options is `-fsSL` (`-f` is the short version of `--fail`).

Comment: what if the command fail with because it asks a yes or no question?

Comment: Thanks!  This is the only solution that worked for me, ie `curl -fsSL https://starship.rs/install.sh | bash -s -- --yes`.

Answer (score 21):

Other alternatives:

```
curl http://foo.com/script.sh | bash /dev/stdin arguments
bash <( curl http://foo.com/script.sh ) arguments
```

Comment: All methods differ on $0 argument. For "-s" it's "bash", for "/dev/stdin" it's "/dev/stdin" and "<(...)"  gives $0 argument like "/dev/fd/63".

Comment: First alternative works with script arguments beginning with a `-`, i.e. options

Comment: Please give an example for a argument to let me know the format

Answer (score -1):

Building on others' answers, if you want your bash script to use pipes, try:

```sh
cat myfile.txt | \
bash -c "$(curl http://example.com/script.sh )" -s arg1 arg2
```

Example [usage](https://github.com/sohale/snippets/blob/master/bash-magic/bash-from-url.sh):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export MYURL="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sohale/snippets/master/bash-magic/add-date.sh"
curl http://www.google.com | \
bash -c "$(curl -L $MYURL )" -s "       >>>>> next line "
```

If you use bit.ly to shorten the url, don't forget the `-L`.