# Renci.SshNet SshClient All commands are not working

Tags: c#, ssh

I'm using SshClient from Renci.SshNet and i have noticed that all the commands are not effective on the remote server.

For example, that one works fine :

```
mySSH.RunCommand( "touch test");
```

will create a file on the remote server.

but this one won't do anything :

```
mySSH.RunCommand( "nohup dnx web &");
```

I searched all over the internet and i'm so disapointed cause nobody talk about that.

Mostly, all commands that are simple like create a file or a folder, but strong commands like executing a script or starting my application (the most important) just simply don't want to do anything.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run this command when you log in over ssh as the same user Ssh.Net is using?

Comment: have you tried running 'file.sh' without 'bash' in front of it?

Comment: Yes for both. Everything work when i'm on ssh session from putty for example. The command 'bash' was an example. If i do chmod +x on my .sh file and then i try executing ./file.sh that wont work. Also, many commands don't works at all

Comment: It might be worth trying the approaches in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141841/passing-parameters-to-bash-when-executing-a-script. i.e. using CreateCommand and Execute, or using curl

Comment: I will try by this way thank you, and i will report here what i have done.

Comment: I don't understand anything from this topic. First, i don't see what the point of using curl here, i don't have any url to pass to it. Then, i tryed to load in a string from a file what i want to do, like the person in the other topic :             cmd = client.CreateCommand(string.Format("sh -x -s < {0}", script));                 but that don't even work. I don't think you really got my problem.

Comment: I just want to add more information, i can run "sh script.sh", but only commands like touch or mkdir can be used. I can't use screen, or dnx (the most important here).