# Pass args for script when going thru pipe

Tags: bash

I have this example shell script:

```
echo /$1/
```

So I may call

```
$ . ./script 5
# output: /5/
```

I want to pipe the script into sh(ell), but can I pass the arg too ?

```
cat script | sh 
# output: //
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can pass arguments to the shell using the `-s` option:

```
cat script | bash -s 5
```

Comment: Or  preferably `bash -s 5 < script`, if `bash` really just needs to read a script from a file (and not a more complicated pipeline).

Comment: @chepner: If it were actually reading from a file and not a more complicated pipeline, then it would be better to do `(ba)sh script 5`.

Comment: not works for `-p` like (which starts from dash)
`cat script | bash -s -a -b -c`
see answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25563308/983232

Comment: if I want to pass "-i" to my program, cat script | bash -s -i does not work!! -i is interpreted by bash! How? I tried escaping it but nothing.

Answer (score 49):

Use `bash -s -- <args>`

e.g, install google cloud sdk

`~ curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash -s -- --disable-prompts`

Answer (score 19):

```
cat script | sh -s -- 5
```

The `-s` argument tells `sh` to take commands from standard input and not to require a filename as a positional argument. (Otherwise, without `-s`, the next non-flag argument would be treated as a filename.)

The `--` tells sh to stop processing further arguments so that they are only picked up by the script (rather than applying to `sh` itself).  This is useful in situations where you need to pass a flag to your script that begins with `-` or `--` (e.g.: `--dry-run`) that must be ignored by `sh`.  Also note that a single `-` is equivalent to `--`.

```
cat script | sh -s - --dry-run
```

Comment: Where is behavior like this documented? I tried `man sh` and `sh --help` on Mac

Comment: @francojposa [Here's one place](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/sh/) although I usually just type `man sh` into Google.