# Passing Flags to a Piped Script

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I have written a shell script to configure a development environment and and retrieving using cURL. The script takes up to 3 flags, -d, -f and -s.

How do I pass the flags to the shell script?

Here is the command to run the bash script:

```
$ curl -sL https://example.com/setup.sh | bash
```

Here is my first (failed) attempt to pass flags to the script:

```
$ curl -sL https://example.com/setup.sh | bash -dfs
  bash: -d: invalid option
```

Can anyone explain how to do this?

Comment: try adding `--` to signal the end of bash arguments and the start of command arguments: `curl -sL https://example.com/setup.sh | bash -- -dfs`

Comment: @joshmeranda, that causes bash to treat `-dfs` as a filename to execute (that being the default way the first non-option argument is parsed).

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [Pass args for script when going thru pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14693100/7939871)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-s` argument:

```
curl -sL https://example.com/setup.sh | bash -s -- -dfs
```

Comment: I think this is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693100/pass-args-for-script-when-going-thru-pipe

Comment: @LéaGris, agreed, thank you. Converted to community wiki, and lent my dupehammer to the close vote.