# How can I pass parameter into bash while scripts it executes are piped in

Tags: bash

What I meant is when I am executing bash scripts using this kind of formart:

```
bash < <( curl http://rvm.io/releases/rvm-install-head )
```

or

```
curl http://rvm.io/releases/rvm-install-head | bash
```

How can I pass in extra parameters along with this execution?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean something as simple as `curl http://rvm.io/releases/rvm-install-head -otherparam | bash -moreparams -yetmoreparams`?

Comment: I just find this question is duplicated with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642915/passing-parameters-to-bash-when-executing-a-script-fetched-by-curl?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Add parameters after `-s` switch.

Example of use:

```
echo 'echo params count: ${#@}, params: $@' | bash -s param1 param2
```

Output:

```
params count: 2, params: param1 param2
```