# Pass parameters to bash script fetched via curl

Tags: bash, curl, argument-passing, google-cloud-platform, non-interactive

This is a question looking for a different syntax aside from the following three:

```
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash -s arg1 arg2
curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash /dev/stdin arg1 arg2
bash <( curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com ) arg1 arg2
```

for passing arguments to a script fetched via curl ... because none of the ones listed work with the `gcloud` script that I'm trying to install silently onto a VM.

I've already looked into these but didn't find a 4th alternative to try out:

- [passing arguments to an interactive program non interactively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392525/passing-arguments-to-an-interactive-script-non-interactively)
- [passing parameters to bash when executing a script fetched by curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642915/passing-parameters-to-bash-when-executing-a-script-fetched-by-curl)
- [Execute bash script from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735666/execute-bash-script-from-url)

Comment: If possible, please help improve the question and leave comments here when down-voting. Thanks!

Comment: Use `xargs` to pass parameters to a script.

Answer (score 1):

Circling back, turns out to be a very niche answer, as folks from google support provided this syntax:

`export CLOUDSDK_CORE_DISABLE_PROMPTS=1; curl -s https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash &>/tmp/gcloud_install_$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M).log`